# Pandas equivalent of max(lower triangle, upper triangle) on square matrix-like dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have a DataFrame `df` with double index (`i` and `j`) which I treat as a (square and sparse) matrix.
At some point I need to do the operation that:

1. compares cell element `df(i,j)` with its transpose `df(j,i)`
2. finds the one for which column `u` is greater
3. removes the smaller one from the matrix

How can I do it in pandas?
I have a naive `.iterrows()` solution which got stuck for matrix dimensions greater that several hundreds:

```
for _,s in df.iterrows():
    if (s.j,s.i) in df.index:
        if df.loc[s.j,s.i]['u']>s['u']:
            df = sg.drop(i,axis=0)
```

This is the data in `df` (I am not sure how to paste data from jupyter to SO, but let's try this):

```
i   j   origin_i    destination_i   ttrav_i treq_i  origin_j    destination_j   ttrav_j treq_j  i   j   u   u_i u_j t   t_oo_i_j    delay   t_od_j_i    t_dd_i_j                                                                
281 230 4.627953e+07    46378182.0  455.0   502.0   3.514366e+08    27471867.0  341.0   719.0   281 230 41.7    21.45   20.25   619 234 17.0    292 93
52  456 3.841813e+09    46374243.0  975.0   2586.0  4.962112e+09    46342032.0  808.0   2739.0  52  456 200.4   186.90  13.50   1148    183 30.0    774 191
163 456 4.652382e+07    46378182.0  1133.0  2178.0  4.962112e+09    46342032.0  808.0   2739.0  163 456 61.3    45.15   16.15   1545    558 -3.0    799 188
435 347 4.653102e+07    297095278.0 994.0   1333.0  4.648040e+07    46342898.0  894.0   1708.0  435 347 78.5    28.85   49.65   1289    302 -73.0   836 151
323 383 2.104392e+09    46375508.0  734.0   3070.0  4.641315e+07    46345887.0  603.0   3391.0  323 383 183.5   98.05   85.45   969 338 17.0    441 190
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and expected output? What is `sg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first introduce a new column with the transposed u (i.e. the u-value of the transposed index). Then we remove any rows where u is smaller than the transposed u.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( { 'i': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                     'j': [2, 3, 2, 5, 4],
                     'u': [10, 20, 30, 50, 40]})
df = df.set_index(['i','j'])

print(df)

df['u_transposed'] = df.reindex(index=df.swaplevel().index)['u'].values
df = df[~(df.u<df.u_transposed)].drop(columns='u_transposed')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
# original matrix
      u
i j    
1 2  10
2 3  20
3 2  30
4 5  50
5 4  40

# result
      u
i j    
1 2  10
3 2  30
4 5  50
```

Comment: @Intelligent-Infrastructure   I hope I got it right, if not please comment with the expected output for my example data. It makes things much easier for all if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with the expected output.

Comment: Yep, I think that is ok. Let me check if that produces the expected result and how well it scales (e.g. for 10k x 10k matrices)

Comment: cool, works like charm. `%timeit` for 3000 x 3000 matrix: `67.9 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`